# How to space divs that are stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css, css-position

So, this is my code:

```css
.headline {
  font-size: 61px;
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro Medium', sans-serif;
  /* font-weight: 700; */
  color: rgb(81, 83, 74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: .9;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603, 0, 0, 1.00025484199796, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603, 0, 0, 1.00025484199796, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603, 0, 0, 1.00025484199796, 0, 0);
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: auto;
  left: 61.909px;
  top: 230px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">WE BELIEVE</div>
<div class="headline">GREAT PEOPLE</div>
<div class="headline">DESERVE TOP</div>
<div class="headline">REWARDS.</div>
<div class="subhead">Make your mark at RapidScale.</div>
```

[In JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DizaBlah/nbk06feo/5/) it looks a lot better than [how it renders in my browser](https://ahcoolthanks.com/test/GSAP/):

I am not sure why these produce different results, but basically I just want the lines to stack on top of each other instead of in-line. Can you please help me?

Comment: Will a link work better?
https://ahcoolthanks.com/test/GSAP/

Answer (score 0):

Remove any `absolute` positioning. It's not needed. Nest the code in a `wrapper` and simplify it with `flex`. Specify `flex-direction: column;` then you can specify a `gap` for however much you want them spaced.

```css
.headline {
  font-size: 61px;
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro Medium', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(81, 83, 74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: .9;
  margin: auto;
  width: 490px;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="headline">WE BELIEVE</div>
  <div class="headline">GREAT PEOPLE</div>
  <div class="headline">DESERVE TOP</div>
  <div class="headline">REWARDS.</div>
  <div class="subhead">Make your mark at RapidScale.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it's closer: https://ahcoolthanks.com/test/GSAP/

Comment: @DizaBlah remove the `position: absolute;` set on the `div` and `*` and remove `margin: auto;` from `headline`. it will work just fine. Also, nest your `subhead` within the wrapper and add `justify-content: center;` to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The issuer is caused by you setting `position : absolute` in both `banner * {}` and `.headline {}`. The presence of either causes the headlines to collapse to the same spot.

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k3vu5fx/) I was able to replicate the problem by adding `position : absolute` to `div {}`.

Replacing the `position : absolute` with `position : relative` for `.headline {}` should fix this issue, as demonstrated in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmzkdjpv/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your .wrapper & .headline with my given css and it'll work perfectly.

```css
.headline {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 61px;
    font-family: 'Gotham Pro Medium', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(81, 83, 74);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: .9;
    -moz-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603,0,0,1.00025484199796,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603,0,0,1.00025484199796,0,0);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 0.99960015993603,0,0,1.00025484199796,0,0);
    left: 61.909px;
    top: 230px;
    width: 490px;
    height: 55px;
    z-index: 11;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 628px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="headline">WE BELIEVE</div>
  <div class="headline">GREAT PEOPLE</div>
  <div class="headline">DESERVE TOP</div>
  <div class="headline">REWARDS.</div>
</div>
```

[You can check my edit of your code here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU8W7.jpg)